# Looking for monitoring tool for JetBrains DataGrip

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, pgadmin, datagrip

I am looking for a monitoring tool like [PgAdmin3 Server status monitoring tool](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22/status.html) for Jetbrains DataGrip:

[image: PgAdmin3 Server status monitoring tool]

Maybe there exist some extension but I couldn't find it.

Comment: There is a huge probability that in 2018.2 DataGrip will show you ALL queries which are performed from DG wether they are internal (DG runs) or user's ones.

Comment: @moscas still a probability or already a reality? or you guys wait for a youtracker ticket?

Comment: DataGrip now stores all the queries that were run in the SQL log. To observe it go to Help - Show SQL log in...

Comment: @moscas: Another good to have would be the realtime graph of number of active connections, inserts etc. like pgAdmin does.

Comment: Yes, but it is more an admin-side feature and is not implemented yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-299

Answer (score 1):

DataGrip at the moment could show active sessions along with scheduled refresh feature.

[image: sessions]